# Behavior of static variable with different User logins

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am bit confused with some implementation,Here is the my problem,

1. Two users can login to the system.(User A,B)
2. They login same time with different user names and passwords

We assume, `Employee` class has a `static` variable call `age`

User A change the age value to 45, after that user B change the age value to 28, then both save the changes.

so what would be the real values of A and B?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, "age" should be an instance variable, not static - a static variable is shared by all the instances of a class.

In the example you gave, the last set value is the one "which sticks", assuming you are working in a non clustered environment (ie, shatic variables are shared in classes instantiated in the same virtual machine).

Answer (score 1):

A and B, in this scenario, don't have an age. The `Employee` class has an age. A static field is associated to a class, and not to an instance of the class. So the `Employee.age` field would have the value 28.

Read more about static members in [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Static variables** have only **one copy shared by each object** that is using that
whereas 
**instance variables have different copies for different objects**

In your case as variable is static so the variable have first **value 45**

and then overwritten by **value 28.**

Comment: Abhishekkumar so if I have an app and userb login and then usera, the usera variables such names or lastname are overwritten, i am talking about in client - server envoriment

Comment: Can you please share the full code over here so that i can answer correctly or more specific question you want to ask